# Using Enum to store numerical constants

Tags: c++, enums

I recently came across code which was similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Example {
private:
    enum {
        BufSize = 4096,
        MsgSize = 200 * 1024,
        HeaderFieldLen = 16
    };
public:
    int getBufSize() {
        return BufSize;
    }
};

int main() {
    Example ex;
    printf("%d\n", ex.getBufSize());
    return 0;
}
```

A class was essentially storing constants in an enum and using their values in its member functions.

Is this a valid use of an enum and if so, is there any reason to store constants in this way, as opposed to in a `struct` or as regular `const` class member variables?

Comment: It's a C-ism, but it's still valid (if slightly obscure) C++ code.

Comment: "at runtime by their name" ??

Comment: @AndreasPapadopoulos So this usage would be in some ways similar to using preprocessor macros to define constants?

Comment: Just personal opinion, but this is a poor use of enums, as they are meant to be used to store sequential data, such as days of the week or months in the year. `const` values would be a much better choice, and are type safe.

Comment: Using enums in this way was the only way to have in-class numeric constants in older versions of C++ (before in-class `static const` variables that didn't require definition).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways of naming numerical constants in order to avoid [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). Using enumerators are one of them.

The advantage of this method over regular `const` variables is that enumerators are not variables. Therefore, they are not stored as variables during run-time, they are simply used by the compiler, at compile-time.

> [from the comments]
>   So this usage would be in some ways similar to using preprocessor macros to define constants?

The downside of macros is (mainly) type safety. Macros have no type, so the compiler cannot check for you whether the types match where you use them. Also, while macros are used in C, they are very rarely used in C++ because we have better tools at our disposal.

In C++11, a better way to name these constants is to use `constexpr` members.

```
constexpr int BufSize = 4096;
constexpr int MsgSize = 200 * 1024;
constexpr int HeaderFieldLen = 16;
```

The above code replaces the following.

```
enum {
    BufSize = 4096,
    MsgSize = 200 * 1024,
    HeaderFieldLen = 16
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**It's valid**.

In the early days, not all compilers support `static const data member` very well. So you have to use this `enum` hack to simulate a static const integer data member.

Now, since compilers have supported `static const data member` very well, you don't have use this hack.

```
// in example.h
class Example {
    static const int BufSize = 4096;
};

// in example.cpp
const int Example::BufSize; // definition
```

Comment: Well the Enum is still much better than the static const data member since you have to pollute your cpp with initialization. :(. - For ints.